# Convert a column from pandas dataframe from float to int

Tags: python, pandas

When I want to do the following command(learned from the other question), there is a warning. How to avoid this warning?

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].astype(int)
```

/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app

Comment: It seems like your dataframe was extracted as a slice from another dataframe. The accepted answer gives you bad advice. Instead, what you should do is to create a copy using `df = df.copy()` and then do the assignment. Never disable warnings on pandas, they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable chained assignments.

```
# Disable chained assignments
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this way rather than changing configurations though this would take more resources. With abundant memory or small size data, it doesn't matter.

```
df_ = df.copy()
df_['Class'] = df_['Class'].astype(int)
```

FYI

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy